# The PayPal IPN issue (Sandbox Environment),

Tags: paypal-sandbox, paypal-ipn, paypal-subscriptions

### The PayPal IPN Issue

The problem is that **we got the IPN turned on**, with a valid url (**not localhost, our real one**), but after we got paid (**Subscriptions**), we receive no IPN massage. It has just not being generated at all. We used to receive the ipn's but after 28.04.2021 it just stopped being generated.

---

Does someone has the same issue or can advise me what can be done to get the IPN fixed?

Answer (score 0):

Only thing to do is log into the sandbox receiver account at https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/webscr?cmd=_display-ipns-history to see if anything is being generated and attempted to send.  If nothing is, contact PayPal for support as it's likely a temporary bug/sandbox issue.

Comment: Yeah, but the main thing is that I got only the "No IPN messages were found for the past 24 hours." message for a few days. It's just not being generated.

Comment: Contact PayPal for support.

Comment: They are not actually interested in...All that i got is - perhaps the problem is on your side, with the server (We've actually been texting for a few days, but still no help from the PayPal support, just some common replies). So, I was looking for the help in here.

Comment: Since this is subscriptions, give an example of a profile ID you created with a notify_url .  Tell them there is nothing in your IPN history (  https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/webscr?cmd=_display-ipns-history  ), and ask them why. If your server was the issue, the failed deliveries would show in the history.

Comment: I'm having the same issue right now as well.  IPNs don't appear to be sending for subscription payments via sandbox.